# Iterative replacement of substrings in bash

Tags: bash, loops, awk, sed, scripting

I'm trying to write a simple script to make several replacements in a big text file. I've a "map" file which contains the records to be searched and replaced,one per line,separated by a *space*, and a "input" file where I need the changes to be done. The examples files and the script I wrote are beneath.

Map file

```
 new_0 old_0
 new_1 old_1
 new_2 old_2
 new_3 old_3
 new_4 old_4
```

Input file

`itsa(old_0)single(old_2)string(old_1)with(old_5)ocurrences(old_4)ofthe(old_3)records`

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r mapline ; do

mapf1=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} {print $1}' <<< "$mapline"`
mapf2=`awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} {print $2}' <<< "$mapline"`

    for line in $(cat "input") ; do

       if [[ "${line}" == *"${mapf2}"* ]] ; then

       sed "s/${mapf2}/${mapf1}/g" <<< "${line}"    
    fi

    done < "input"

done < "map"
```

The thing is that the searches and replaces are made correctly, but I can't find a way to save the output of each iteration and work over it in the next. So, my output looks like this:

```
itsa(new_0)single(old_2)string(old_1)withocurrences(old_4)ofthe(old_3)records
itsa(old_0)single(old_2)string(new_1)withocurrences(old_4)ofthe(old_3)records
itsa(old_0)single(new_2)string(old_1)withocurrences(old_4)ofthe(old_3)records
itsa(old_0)single(old_2)string(old_1)withocurrences(old_4)ofthe(new_3)records
itsa(old_0)single(old_2)string(old_1)withocurrences(new_4)ofthe(old_3)records
```

Yet, the desired output would look like this:

```
itsa(new_0)single(new_2)string(new_1)withocurrences(new_4)ofthe(new_3)records
```

May anyone bring some light in this darkly waters??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of reading the line and then using awk to split it into mapf1 and mapf2, just do: `while read -r mapf1 mapf2 remainder; do`  The read will then assign the first field to `$mapf1`, the second to `$mapf2`, and everything else to `$remainder`

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Improving the existing script

Improvements:

- Use `"$()"` instead of ``` `` ```. It supports whitespace and is easier to read.
- Don't execute sed for each line. sed already loops over all lines and is faster than a loop in bash.

The adapted script:

```
text="$(< input)"
while read -r mapline; do
        mapf1="$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} {print $1}' <<< "$mapline")"
        mapf2="$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} {print $2}' <<< "$mapline")"
        text="$(sed "s/${mapf2}/${mapf1}/g" <<< "$text")"
done < "map"
echo "$text"
```

The variable `$text` contains the complete input file and is modified in each iteration. The output of this script is the file after all replacements were done.

#### Alternative approach

Convert the map file into a pattern for sed and execute sed just once using that pattern.

```
pattern="$(sed 's#\(.*\) \(.*\)#s/\2/\1/g#' map)"
sed "$pattern" input
```

The first command is the conversion step. The file

```
new_0 old_0
new_1 old_1
...
```

will result in the pattern

```
s/old_0/new_0/g
s/old_1/new_1/g
...
```

Comment: I'd want to qualify the statement re: `[[ "${line}" == *"${mapf2}"* ]]` -- in normal circumstances (with smaller strings) that operation is far faster than invoking `sed` (or any other external command); it's only with a very large string that it's the inverse. (I'd also suggest `=` rather than `==` to encourage finger memory compliant with POSIX `test`, though either is legal in `[[ ]]`).

Comment: You also might use `$(<input)` instead of `$(cat input)` to avoid subprocess overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the comments. `<` clearly is better than `cat`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Looking at this again, by the way -- why the `awk` statements, rather than relying on `read` to parse out individual columns? (ie. `while read -r mapf1 mapf2; do ...`)

Comment: The `awk` command was part of the original question. I did not bother to change that part, because the alternative approach should be used anyway.

Comment: Thanks Scowi, you really helped me!

Comment: Charles, thank you for your input, I'm very new to scripting, so I didn't know that `read` can parse the individual columns, but I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Actually, one correction -- as that was given, it would include the second column *and onward* in `mapf2`; to only include the second column's contents and not the rest of the line, it should be `while read -r mapf1 mapf2 _; do ...` -- with `_` being a placeholder variable name by convention.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in `GNU Awk` as follows,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$2]=$1; next} \
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)\
    {for(key in hash) \
    {if (match ($i,key)) {$i=sprintf("(%s)",hash[key];break;)}}}print}' \
    map-file FS='[()]' OFS= input-file
```

produces an output as,

```
itsa(new_0)single(new_2)string(new_1)withold_5ocurrences(new_4)ofthe(new_3)records
```

Comment: After all mine was approaching this one so ++.

Comment: @JamesBrown: Yup, the only _ugly_ part was using `sprintf()`, do you know a way to fix that with a proper `OFS` as `()`?

Comment: Pretty little `gensub` and `\\1`, `\\2` ;D

Answer (score 1):

Another in Gnu awk, using `split` and ternary operator(s):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[$2]=$1; next }  
{
    n=split($0,b,"[()]")    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)       
        printf "%s%s",(i%2 ? b[i] : (b[i] in a? "(" a[b[i]] ")":"")),(i==n?ORS:"")
}' map foo
itsa(new_0)single(new_2)string(new_1)withocurrences(new_4)ofthe(new_3)records
```

First you read in the `map` to `a` hash. When processing the `file`, `split` all records by `(` and `)`. Every other could be in the `map` (`i%2==0`). While `printf`ing test with ternary operator if matches are found from `a` and when there is a match, output it parenthesized.

Comment: somehow, it looks neater than mine, `++`